# Can't connect to server using Connection String

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

So here is my code:

```
Private adoConnection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Private adoadapterFillDSUsers As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
Private ServerName As String = ""
Private ConnectionString As String = ""

 Private Sub adoconn()
        adoConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
        adoConnection.ConnectionString = DataManager.DataManager.ConnectionString
    End Sub
    Public Sub ContinueInit()
        ReadRegistry()
        Dim currRegKey As RegistryKey
        Dim newRegKey As RegistryKey
        currRegKey = Registry.CurrentConfig
        Try
            newRegKey = currRegKey.OpenSubKey("Hoh_Dev\Data")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return
        End Try
        Try
            MREZA = newRegKey.GetValue("Mreza")
            ServerName = newRegKey.GetValue("ServerName")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return
        End Try

        If MREZA = "D" Then
            ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ServerName & ";Integrated Security = SSPI;"
        Else
            If MREZA = "W" Then
                ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DataBaseName & ";user id=xxx;pwd=xxx;"
            End If
        End If
        adoconn()
    End Sub
```

I am already loosing my mind since every time when I want to connect to my server and use this:

```
If adoConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then adoConnection.Open()
Try
  DataManager.DataManager.adoCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch OpenConnectionError As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
End Try
```

I got this error:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

I call `ContinueInit` sub from Form Load Event:

```
 Private Sub LogIn_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ContinueInit()

        Me.TextBox1.Focus()
        Me.TransparencyKey = BackColor
        Me.Button2.Visible = False
        Me.Button1.Visible = False
        TextBox2.PasswordChar = "*"
    End Sub
```

The code cracks at `adoConnection.Open()` which means I can't even open a connection to my server so I can execute SQL query, which leads me only to a thing that I didn't setup something good.

Comment: What error message are you getting?  Have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: Telling us "the code cracks" is not very useful. Maybe you could tell us the actual error message you receive.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Here you can see the error message:
http://i.imgur.com/HSaXCwS.png

Comment: @AaronBertrand take a look at my comment abobe

Comment: The message says it all, the connectionstring property is not initialized. This means that the adoconn() method doesn't refer to the same variable initialized in the ContinueInit method

Comment: Instead of a screen shot you are forcing people to find in the comments and click to view (some of whom won't be able to see it because that site is blocked), why don't you type that error message into the question?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have added that text into the question, thank you for pointing me what would be much better.

Comment: @Steve this is the first time to see something like this since I am using EXACT SAME code for ConnectionString into one my projects and it works very fine for more then 3 years. I just copy/paste almost the same code for connection with minor changes.

Comment: What is the name of this class? When you initialize the connectionstring you use DataManager.DataManager.ConnectionString. This should be a reachable property from this class

Comment: This question doesn't deserve a down vote as the user has (1) posted code and what he's tried, (2) indicated that he's successfully used this before now, and (3) corrected his questions when suggestions were made to him in the comments.  Those are not behaviors of people who deserve a down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection object does not have a `ConnectionString` filled in.

Not sure what DataManager.DataManager is but I am guesing that you are doing something with creating a shared instance of the DataManager class in your DataManager class and you called it DataManager. (very confusing) But, I would guess you need to look into this and **Step Through Your Code** to find why the connection string is an empty string.

Comment: Yes, DataManager is exactly what you wrote. Honestly I am looking into it for more then 12 hours and can't find a single problem, since as I said before that is the same code (with minor changes) I use in my other project which works well.

Comment: And I "say" here what `ConnectionString` is:
`ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DataBaseName & ";user id=xxx;pwd=xxx;"`

Comment: @Nidzaaaa There is no evidence in your posted code that you are actually calling the `ContinueInit` method.

Comment: @LarsTech just added that part of code, I call it from Load event of form

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `DataManager.DataManager.adoCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` and see what the `DataManager.DataManager.ConnectionString` is. I would gues an empty string. If so, set break points everywhere you set the `ConnectionString` property. If you DO hit a breakpoint, then look at your call stack to make sure you are where you should be. If it does not hit the breakpoint, then I assume you are never calling `ContinueInit` anywhere in your code PRIOR to calling `DataManager.DataManager.?Whatever?`

Comment: @Steve I just did that and you were right, `ConnectionString` is just a empty string, but I don't have an idea why.
Also, my code went trough `ContinueInit` sub so that means I am calling that sub, as I wrote in my previous post edit.
I would really like to solve this puzzle after more then 12 hours and thank you for trying to help me out.

Comment: FINALY, I went trough that.
I opened connection!!!
Now I have got another problem, sadly.
When I go trough code in debug mode, I passed connection opening part and after that code cracks on `ExecuteNonQuery` part (Just bellow connection opening) with a error message `String[2]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.`

Comment: @Nidzaaaa Change your code to this: `adoConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString`  Your `DataManager.DataManager` stuff looks irrelevant.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `DataManager.DataManager.adoCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` and both lines that start with `ConnectionString = ` Which one hits first? should be the line in the `ContinueInit`. If you still dont have it after this. Try posting the code that is 'Cracking'. You posted the `adoconn` code but not the `adoCommand` code.

Comment: @Lars I solved that problem just 2 minutes ago.
In the part of code when I say ` If MREZA = "W" ...` when I wanted to declare what `ConnectionString` is, I just added `DataManager` class instance, since seems like I was calling wrong `ConnectionString` and that's why I have got only empty string, nothing else. But now I have another problem in line bellow when I am trying to execute query, and I guess that might be a problem with a StoredProcedure?

Comment: @Nidzaaaa Different question.  If Steve helped you, mark his post as the answer and document a new question.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it. I would add an ELSE in your `If MREZA = "W" Then`, I hate open if statements. If you run into more issues (with SP), you should create a new post rather than piggy-back on this one.  Cheers.

Comment: @Steve Yes, it hits the line from `ContinueInit` first.

Comment: @Steve sure I will open a new post with a new question, thank you very much for your time you spend with me trying AND succeeding to help me out with this (huge for me) problem.